# JQuery and ASP.Net MVC, youtube caption plugin like Subtitle Horse

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, youtube, caption

I am trying to look for a plugin like the one you find at the Subtitle Horse.
http://subtitle-horse.com/

Unfortunately it just works for PHP.

I also bought http://activeden.net/item/subtitle-video-player-flex-editor-javascript/full_screen_preview/129075 to use for adding translations.
Worked perfect, but it just works with local files, not with youtube.

If somebody have any idea where I can get something similar to my application, with Jquery in preference, please let me know.

best regards,
Tito